# I can submit request by browser, but cURL says couldn't connect to host, why?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to call some http web-service with php cURL. I can make the request and get successful response when I try calling that service in the browser. But whenever I try to call it via cURL, it fails with error message: `couldn't connect to host`

The code I am using here is as follows:

```
$url = 'http://myserviceurl.com';
$fields = array(
                        'field1' => urlencode('field1value'),
                        'field2' => urlencode('field2value'),
                        'field3' => urlencode('field3value')                        
                );

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if($result === false)
{    
    echo sprintf('<span>%s</span>CURL error:',curl_error($ch));
    return;
}
```

How can I fix/diagnose this?

Comment: Maybe the site denies requests from useragent curl? Try spoofing your useragent by using `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "My User Agent" );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Bijoy(In the another answer) is correct. There was a proxy set in the browser. I changed the code to add the proxy with `CURLOPT_PROXY` like this:

```
$proxy = '<my-proxy-ip>:<proxy-port>';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if you have a browser based http proxy set

Comment: And what can I do to fix that for cURL?

Comment: please refer man page of curl, -x, --proxy <[protocol://][user:password@]proxyhost[:port]> , can be used I presume

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting SSL_VERIFYER to false?

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);